# How First_open is related to previous_first_open_count Params_Int_Value

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am observing in most of the cases it increment by one  on re-installing the app but there are cases (around 10 %) where in bigquery I saw multiple first_open entries but previous_first_open_count Params_Int_Value is not increasing

Comment: Are you running on Android or iOS?

Comment: I am running this on android

Comment: I am still not clear what the problem is. Why do you think it is the problem that previous_first_open_count didn't increase? If an app is installed for the first time by a user, the previous count is 0. If an app is installed with Analytics already, then gets re-installed again, the previous count will increase. If an app is installed without Analytics, and later is installed with Analytics, previous count won't increase. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense that is also my understanding but my ask is sometime the count is not increment on re-install . In firebase against one device I saw multiple installs (First_open) but previous count is still 0 . Ideally it should increment.Also I couldn't understand what app without analytics means .Does it mean app that doesn't have Firebase SDK . If yes then I am referring to App with analytics case only

Comment: How did you see multiple installs on one device? Did it have the same instance ID?

Comment: No, app instance ID was different for each install

Comment: @TarunKakkar did you find the answer? I posted a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712259/firebase-first-open-event-previous-first-open-count-param-logic